# How to integrate Open Street map in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-maps, openstreetmap

I want to use Open Street Map instead of Google maps, 
so i use [react-native-maps-osmdroid](https://github.com/fqborges/react-native-maps-osmdroid) to handle it

but i can't see any Map in my View so should i add something when setup it?

> "I don't have Google key cuz react-native-maps require it so that's reason to use react-native-maps-osmdroid"

screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
import MapView, {Marker} from 'react-native-maps-osmdroid';

class MapTest extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <MapView
          style={{flex: 1}}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}>
          <Marker
            title="Home"
            color="#f00"
            coordinate={{
              latitude: 37.78825,
              longitude: -122.4324,
              latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
              longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
            }}
          />
        </MapView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default MapTest;
```

Answer (score 2):

You still need API key with [react-native-maps-osmdroid](https://github.com/fqborges/react-native-maps-osmdroid/blob/HEAD/docs/installation.md).

> The actual map implementation depends on the platform. On Android, one has to use >Google Maps, which in turn requires you to obtain an API key for the Android SDK.

You can get API key for free. Just follow [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key)

Comment: to get an API Key it should create a billing account. so I will add my visa card information but my visa not accepted from google.

Comment: @OliverD I have used google maps with react native before and have never had to enter a credit card number.

Comment: @OliverD you can get API key from https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials I just did it.

Comment: weird I got it, but I can't enable Directions for no reason

Comment: the main reason to use it i have to static points and i want to render a direction between them and consideration of real routes in maps, not just a line

Answer (score 0):

MapView seems to have loaded. You'll still require an api-key as their installation instructions suggest.

If that's okay then check that if your AndroidManifest.xml file contains

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

If not add this line to AndroidManifest.xml and for iOS, you have to configure **App Transport Security** in your app.